# Is there a workaround for sending large payloads to API clients?

Tags: winapi, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2019

According to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366781/), circa 2012, the Win32 API HTTP server [`HttpSendResponseEntityBody()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/http/nf-http-httpsendresponseentitybody?redirectedfrom=MSDN) data structure that is utilized by SSRS has a hard limit on the `EntityChunkCount` of 9999. That appears to be the max size for an array of pointers to [`HTTP_DATA_CHUNK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/http/ns-http-http_data_chunk) structures.

After troubleshooting a report that successfully renders out a ~500 mb payload but fails on the HTTP response.

There is a painful XLXS report render request that has been critical for years. This year, for some of the larger clients, it has started failing on SSRS HTTP responses, unfortunately. As far as `web.config` goes, all the client max response sizes and request timeouts, and the `ReportingService` max HTTP lengths and timeout settings, are set to very high values.

My question is not whether this been resolved yet, because I am testing on SSRS 2019. Is there a magic machine configuration outside of `web.config` or .NET, perhaps in the registry, that can be modified to increase this limit?

> BaseWorkerRequest::SendHttpResponse(bool), exception=System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range

Reproduce

1. Wrap the ReportExecution2005 service and call the Render() method for the specified report. In this case the timeout is 10 hours the format is xlsx.

...

```
ReportRenderResponse result = new ReportRenderResponse();

ReportExecutionService _execService = new ReportExecution.ReportExecutionService { Timeout = request.ReportTimeout };
_execService.Url = request.ServiceUrl;
_execService.Credentials = request.Credentials;

ParameterValue[] ssrsParams = request.Parameters.Parameters.ToSSRSParameters();

StringBuilder deviceInfo = CreateDeviceInfoForRender(request);

string extension;
string mimeType;
string reportEncoding;
string[] streamIDs = null;
Warning[] warnings = null;
ExecutionInfo reportInfo = _execService.LoadReport(request.ReportPath, null);

if (ssrsParams != null)
    _execService.SetExecutionParameters(ssrsParams, request.ParameterLanguage);

_execService.ExecutionHeaderValue = new ExecutionHeader();
_execService.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID = reportInfo.ExecutionID;

result.Payload = _execService.Render(request.Format.ToSSRSRenderExtension(), deviceInfo.ToString(), out extension, out mimeType, out reportEncoding, out warnings, out streamIDs);
```

...

2. Create a dataset that will produce Render requests similar to the ones below.

| TimeDataRetrieval | TimeProcessing | TimeRendering | Source | Status | ByteCount | RowCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 283278 | 1123501 | 5404015 | Live | rsSuccess | 442238838 | 3446298 |
| 293679 | 1086177 | 5333539 | Live | rsSuccess | 442238838 | 3446298 |
| 373011 | 1083059 | 5268298 | Live | rsSuccess | 442238838 | 3446298 |
| 286151 | 955929 | 5068241 | Live | rsSuccess | 442238838 | 3446298 |
| 320936 | 1097187 | 5191568 | Live | rsSuccess | 442238838 | 3446298 |
| 334839 | 1038722 | 4778627 | Live | rsSuccess | 442238838 | 3446298 |

3. Check the ReportServivce log.

> rshost!rshost!340c!07/13/2022-11:47:12:: e ERROR:
> HttpPipelineCallback::SendResponse(): failed writing response.
> rshost!rshost!340c!07/13/2022-11:47:12:: e ERROR: Failed with win32
> error 0x0057, pipeline=0x0000016EC8CA7D60.
> httpruntime!ReportServer_0-4!340c!07/13/2022-11:47:12:: e ERROR:
> Failed in BaseWorkerRequest::SendHttpResponse(bool),
> exception=System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the
> expected range.    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.HostingInterfaces.IRsHttpPipeline.SendResponse(Void*
> response, Boolean finalWrite, Boolean closeConn)    at
> ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.BaseWorkerRequest.SendHttpResponse(Boolean
> finalFlush)

Comment: Check your math. 256(kb) max per chunk, at 99999 chunks max, would be a max payload of ~24(gb), not 204(mb).  204(mb) at 256(kb) per chunk would be 816 chunks

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - typo, I meant bytes.

Comment: In that case, 256(b) max per chunk, 99999 chunks max, would be a max payload of only 24(mb), not 204(mb). BIG difference, and I can't imagine this API having such a restrictive limitation. How are you determining the max chunk size? There is no size limit being enforced by `HTTP_DATA_CHUNK`. Please provide a [mcve], you are probably just chunking the data incorrectly.

Comment: Dammit, I has the limit wrong too. Edited to 9999.

Comment: 256(b) max per chunk, 9999 max chunks, is only 2.4(mb), that would be even worse. I am no MS employee, but I'm sure this API doesn't restrict payloads that low.

Comment: The fact that somewhere around 200 mb is where the exception starts appearing in the log. The api docs stated a max of 9999.

Comment: Again, please provide a [mcve], and indiicate where the error is being reported. Or else noone will be able to help you diagnose what is really happening.

Comment: I can reproduce this with a ~500MB payload every time. I have been slowly reducing the payload size in an attempt to find a limit.

Comment: [minimum ... reproducible ... example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please.

Comment: My quick perusal of the linked HttpSendResponseEntityBody docs makes me think you are supposed to use a loop, specifying HTTP_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_MORE_DATA
 for the early chunks and 0 for the last.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir - That sounds like socket programming, however, the ssrs ReportExecutrion api supports no such construct.

Comment: @RossBush which is why, again, we need to see a [mcve] representing your actual code, so we can make sure you are using the API correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Added some more info.